# Generate Server side PDF reports with Flutter

Tags: flutter, report

I have a Flutter mobile and WEB application already developed.

I would like to reuse part of the code to generate PDF reports.

This report will reuse GoogleMaps widget already implemented.

Is it possible to render Server Side Flutter Web server / API allowing to generate a PDF report ?

Is PhantomJS a solution that could be evaluated for this ?

Comment: I am also trying to implement something similar. Since its quite easy to put together a PDF report in flutter. At least much easier than doing on the server side. It would be preferable to utilize the rendering capabilities of flutter. The only solution I could think of is to create and show the PDF to the user and then upload to the server in order to send by email. That's my scenario at the moment. But I am open for suggestions. Thx

Comment: Now I've just found this library: https://pub.dev/packages/pdf that seems to be capable of generating a PDF file as a Dart microservice. I am going to experiment with that scenario.